# How do I speed up initial login?

Tags: login, performance, lightdm, debugging

The initial login on my Ubuntu 12.04 machine can take anywhere from 45 seconds to two minutes. If I log out, then log back in again, the login time takes between 4 and 7 seconds.

How can I find out what it making that initial login take so long?

- I'm using LightDM.
- I consider login to be the time from hitting Enter in the LightDM password prompt to the UI appearing in my X session.
- The delay occurs regardless of window manager (I'm using Unity, but the initial Gnome 2 login takes just as long)

**EDIT** Here's the output of bootchart:
[image: Full boothchart output]

Here's a close-up of the interesting bits:
[image]

Comment: Start here: http://www.bootchart.org/ and include the image when you are done ;)